# Why is my Python regular expression not extracting relative URL's from links?

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I have, in Python:

```
links = re.match(r'''<A HREF="(\w+?\.htm)#\w*?">''', workbench)
```

'workbench' is a file read into memory with line separators replaced by spaces; one such file is at: http://pastebin.com/a0LHKXcS

There are some links that don't interest me; they all have lowercase 'a' or 'href'. So far as I can construct, when matched against the file in the pastebin, I should be getting a lot of matches. But so far the re.match() is returning None and not a populated MatchObject I can pull for data. I tried on the command line and cut the regular expression down to be more tolerant of differences, and a search for HREF didn't find anything.

How can I adjust the regular expression (or other factors) so the call gets a populated MatchObject?

Thanks

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/566644)

Comment: Your regex matches only url with one word followed by `.htm#` (i.e. `myPage123.htm#` but not `/dir/my-page.htm`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) only tries to match *at the start* of the string. Use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

Apart from that, lazyr is right: even though this particular regular expression works in this particular instance to find particular hits, you are in general much better off relying on an HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> aa = soup.findAll("a", href=re.compile(r".*#.*"))
>>> for a in aa:
...   print a["href"]
... 
npnf214.htm#P5_18
npnf2140.htm#P6_28
npnf2141.htm#P30_306
npnf2142.htm#P257_10476
npnf2143.htm#P273_20869
npnf2144.htm#P322_41638
npnf2145.htm#P424_60362
npnf2146.htm#P453_82389
npnf2147.htm#P506_110748
npnf2148.htm#P514_110857
npnf2149.htm#P522_112870
npnf2110.htm#P538_115696
npnf2111.htm#P553_120011
npnf2112.htm#P561_131414
npnf2113.htm#P593_136014
npnf2114.htm#P681_155628
npnf2115.htm#P719_167167
npnf2116.htm#P743_173304
npnf2117.htm#P768_186497
npnf2118.htm#P839_201234
npnf2119.htm#P891_222702
npnf2120.htm#P941_235400
npnf2121.htm#P993_248248
npnf2122.htm#P1057_267070
npnf2123.htm#P1085_275404
npnf2124.htm#P1111_287892
npnf2125.htm#P1370_306192
>>>
```